# MySQL - Created index isn't showing up as possible key

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have the following table (it has more data columns, removed them because it would be a long post):

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `memberid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`memberid`),
  KEY `members_lname_ix` (`lastname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1019 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

By default, a user only ever accesses 10-20 rows from this table at a time and it is usually sorted by the lastname column, it's all paginated server side. so I decided to add an index to lastname to help with sorting, however the index does not seem to be working like I would expect it to. when I run  `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY lastname ASC`  I get:

```
id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | extra
1  | simple      | members | ALL  | null          | null | null    | null | 711  | using filesort
```

I can at least confirm the index exists because if I run `SHOW INDEX FROM members` I get:

```
Table   | Non_Unique | Key_name         | Seq_in_ix | Col_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub part | Packed | Null    | Ix type
members | 0          | PRIMARY          | 1         | memberid | A         | 711         | null     | null   | (blank) | BTREE
members | 1          | members_lname_ix | 1         | lastname | A         | 711         | null     | null   | YES     | BTREE
```

if I add `USE INDEX (members_lname_ix)` both possible_keys and key will remain null. However if I add `FORCE INDEX (members_lname_ix)` possible_keys remains null and key shows members_lname_ix. This is my first time trying to apply indexing but to me this doesn't seem very intuitive - it feels like mysql should know that I created an index for lastname, no? I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong here unless I am misunderstanding something. Is the solution here to just keep using `FORCE INDEX`?

Comment: While I believe MySQL does take advantage of indexes for ordering, the lack of mention of it in the documentation for EXPLAIN [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) seems to hint that EXPLAIN will not show this use, only those used for filtering/joining.

Comment: MySQL will use an index to eliminate a file sort if possible. But after creating a new index, you might need to use `ANALYZE TABLE members` to make sure to refresh index statistics, or else the optimizer won't know that the index exists.

Comment: In general, you should not need to use `USE INDEX` or `FORCE INDEX` for such a simple query. I try to use index hints as rarely as possible, because hard-coding index names in my queries makes it harder to drop and rename indexes freely.

Comment: Ya that's why it feels a bit off. In most examples of indexing I see I rarely see them using use/force. It still behaves the same after running `ANALYZE TABLE members`.

I considered also that maybe it's becuase theres only ~700 records so far but I would imagine having an index would still be much more preferable to finding what 10 rows to serve up over doing 700 string comparisons, even to the optimizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to perform that query:

Plan A (as you were expecting):

1. Scan through the index sequentially, reading the entire (estimated) 711 rows.
2. Randomly look up each row in the data BTree.  This involves reading the entire dataset.
3. Deliver the data in order.

Plan B (what it does):

1. Scan through the data, reading all 711 rows.
2. Sort the data
3. Deliver the sorted data.

Plan B does not touch the index at all; this was deemed to be a bigger savings than not having to sort the data.

In a table as tiny as yours, it would be hard to see a difference in speed.  (In my test case, it took under 10 milliseconds either way.)  In huge tables, the difference could be significant.

For optimal pagination, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Comment: I guess I'm misunderstanding the concept of indexing then.. 
I was interpereting it as the index being a quick-reference for the task, applying it to lastname in 'asc' order meaning the database pre-computes the sort and then looks at that for any request for it sorted. The plan I was expecting would, for say a limit 10 offset 20 query, be 1. Scan through the indexes for the 10 desired rows, 2. read only those 10 rows from the actual database, 3. deliver the data. If this is what it IS doing, would it automatically do it on a larger db?

Comment: I did more research on them and I was misunderstanding them. Your response makes more sense now

Comment: @crowdozer - `OFFSET 20` must read 20 rows, but not deliver them.  This gets costly for bigger numbers.  Whether it is just scanning the index or must scan the data, too, depends on things such as the `WHERE` clause.